# What is the APT key for the SonarQube native packages?

Tags: sonarqube

The http://sonar-pkg.sourceforge.net/ page lists the APT repo for installing SonarQube and keeping it up to date via the package manager, which is great! Unfortunately, though, it doesn't list the APT key used to sign those packages, which makes using them a pretty big security risk -- especially since they're only available over HTTP (as opposed to HTTPS).

Are the `deb` packages signed? If so, is the public key posted somewhere that I can download it from?

Thanks!